# IIFE functions in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I found this article, [self-invoking function in JavaScript](http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/) by Minko Gechev, teaching us how to write a JavaScript function that calls itself right after being initialized. I wonder how we can do this in typescript. **I found if I write the code inside `export class ComponentName`, it will not work. 
the code I tried:**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({...})

export class MyComponent{

    @Input() infoes;

    (function(){
        console.log('testing');
    })();
}
```

The error the IDE was showing is `unexpected token. a constructor, accessor, method or property was expected` . I think it has to do with the class concept TypeScript introduced.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. There's no valid JavaScript that's not valid TypeScript. It should work, more info please. What errors are you getting. "It does not work" is never a good enough problem description.

Comment: `(function(){
    console.log('testing');
})();` this is what i tried. When I typed this, the code below it has the red underscore on it saying **"unused label"**. at the same time, the code i tried itself says  **"unexpected token. a constructor, method ... was expected"**.

Comment: @JuanMendes Mind you, a purist would say that TypeScript is not a strict superset of JavaScript because some JavaScript code may yield compilation errors. ;)

Comment: Please show us the entire file, it looks like it is expecting a constructor

Comment: You should consider updating your post with more relevant details: there's nothing wrong with your code; it should work. The challenge you are facing must have surely be elsewhere.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz  I have updated the code, please check it out

Comment: @yeehaah Ok, so you just cannot put functions in classes because TypeScript does not allow that. The fact that it is immediately-invoked is not the issue here. (You cannot have a function there, immediately-invoked or not.) You should edit your question to describe what specific effect you are trying to achieve with that function.

Comment: @Louis I think you can have a function there. but the problem is you cant use the self-invoke format there. Just try to run `class MyComponent{ func(){console.log('testing');}`. it's working.

Comment: @yeehaah What you have there is a *method*, not a *function*. There's a difference. The *method* is attached to instances of `MyComponent`: you have to do `x.func()` where `x` is an instance of `MyComponent`. A *function*, if it were allowed at all there, would presumably be invocable anywhere in the module without having to refer to an instance or even the class itself. You could just call it like this `func()`.

Comment: If you want to invoke something at the beginning, you can use ngOnInit(){...} function. It's triggered by angular after initialization of that component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have is an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression). TypeScript does allow IIFEs, but only in places where expressions are allowed in general. TypeScript does not allow isolated expressions to sit there. This is also disallowed:

```
class Foo {
    1+1;
};
```

However, this uses an IIFE *to initialize a field*, which is allowed:

```
class Foo {
    foo: string = (function bar(){
        console.log("testing");
        return "value";
    }());
};

new Foo();
```

Your're going to see `testing` on the console if this is run.

---

To address the comments, you cannot do this either:

```
class Foo {
    function bar(){
        console.log('testing');
    );
}
```

The above is a *function* in a class. That is different from the following, which is a *method* in a class:

```
class Foo {
    bar(){
        console.log('testing');
    );
}
```

Comment: Under the hood, when transpiled to JavaScript, the `function Foo(){}` will have a `this.foo = (function bar(){...})()`. It's unrelated to Angular btw